# How to convert a list from Google Sheets into Python?

Tags: python, list, google-sheets, copy-paste

I am trying to convert a list of items from Google Sheets, into a list for python.

For example, this is how it looks right now;

**A**

**B**

**C**

**D**

When I want it to look like this in Python;

**['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}**

Is that possible at all, to copy a list of items from Google Sheets into Python? Manually typing everything out is a real pain, so I would love to know whether or not this could be done.

Best wishes,

Bruhammydude

Comment: Does each line represent a cell (i.e. are there blank cells between filled ones)? And does this need to pull from Google Sheets specifically, or would working on a downloaded CSV be fine?

Comment: Yeah, each line is a cell, I could bring it to CSV, a bit new to coding but I'm learning

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Export your Google Sheets as a CSV file
2. use Pandas to read CSV file
3. Select and export column as a list

   df = pandas.read_csv("csv_file_name")
   item_list = df["column_name"].tolist()

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to import the data directly from google sheets, without export to csv, you do it as you like more, writing half line of code.

I was looking fast importing data, and get out of the IDE to do the csv export was annoying me so i looked for a fast direct way.

Here is the way, tested. Ryan Jones tell you how to do it in a 2 min video.
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6WSY9D_ORQ&ab_channel=naas)

And this are the lines of code you need.

```
import pandas as pd
sheet_id = '1WxkdUPn9lUj6T2******7io7MMZvjd08LjYKk35Vf8w'
df = pd.read_csv(f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?format=csv')
print(df.columnhead)
```

Where columhead is the name you gave to your column data
[(see the picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyyQm.png)

The magic line is

```
/export?format=csv
```

Nice